# SEO - Backlinks to main website url better or individual pages

Tags: seo

I have been struggling to understand one basic concept of off-page SEO. Suppose i have a website example.com. Now when i researched for keywords i got the following good keywords

keyword one

keyword two

keyword three

Now what is the best way to do back linkings on good PR websites.

1 - Should i comment,bookmark, make a article, forum comment etc and mention my main website's url www.example.com

OR

2 - I should create individual pages in my website with the keywords i researched. for example. www.example.com/keyword-one , www.example.com/keyword-two, www.example.com/keyword-three

and then i comment,bookmark, make a article, forum comment etc and mention my keyword pages links there ?

What is the best approach towards this ?

Comment: Sigh. Search is not about keywords. That is SEO B.S. Write content expertly and then worry about the nitty gritty. It is the content that matters!

Comment: So but this type of question has been asked time again in various forms.

Comment: Since you mentioned `comment posting, social bookmarks, article submissions, forum comments, PR` I recommend you read SEO guides written by reputable people in the last couple of years, since whatever your reading now is going to end you up with a penalty for low-quality links. The question linked and Moz guides are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basics: Indexation, Content, and Popularity.

- **Indexation**: Searchers' spiders must be able to access all your site without any error.
- **Content**: You need to provide the content you want to rank for.
- **Popularity**: Quality links will help to rank better and faster inside the SERPs.

In order to rank efficiently in searchers (and to focus on your audience) you need an optimal browsing directory or web structure with unique and quality content.

Before generating content you should design your sitemap and define what URLs you need to create to rank for your goal keywords. The more pages you create, the more quality traffic you could catch as long as they are SEO valid.

(In general) you will rank good with your home (domain.com) for brand and general terms with huge searchers but conversion will be low. On the contrary, long-tail terms based on internal URLs such as domain.com/keyword1 would have less traffic but a better percentage of conversion.

So, answering your question, it will depend on your strategy:

- If you want brand awareness, link back to your home
- If you want leads/conversion, link back to long-tail pages

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. What i am confused about is suppose we have a property website. Now i have good content on www.example.com which is my home page, but suppose i have done by keyword research and created one page www.example.com/flats-for-rent-in-london . And this page has all listings of properties and more content which is unique from home page. Now what is a good way here ? Should i create backlinks for my home page or the keyword page www.example.com/flats-for-rent-in-london.

Comment: Assuming you want leads/conversions I'll link www.example.com/flats-for-rent-in-london with anchors such as "rent in London", "flats for rent in London", "cheapest rent in London"...

Comment: So if i am creating these pages based on keywords. I guess there is not need to mention these keywords in meta keywords in home page ?

Comment: Meta keywords Attribute doesn't affect SEO anymore. Just focus on generating quality content and internal links.